# Spring AOP - Pointcuts not triggering

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am just getting started with Spring AOP in my project and am having some problems with getting Spring AOP working correctly.

I have two objects, TransportImpl and SesssionImpl that I would like to profile via AOP.  Both objects(beans) are initialised via Spring.  Both beans are implementations of business
interfaces (Transport and Session).  I can get Aspects applied to the TransportImpl bean to work well, but those applied to the SessionImpl just do not fire.  I can confirm that the
"mySessionMonitor" Aspect is initialised by Spring, and that the SessionImpl object is also initialised without any exceptions or errors.

I have stripped down my PointCuts and Aspect to the most basic form possible.  I would have expected the PointCut *sessionOperation* described below 
to fire when the SessionImpl bean is initialised and the init-method initialise is called.  But this never happens.  What might be going wrong here?

From the configuration file:

```
<bean id="MyTransport" class="my.app.transport.TransportImpl"   scope="singleton" />                
<bean id="MySession" class="my.app.session.SessionImpl" init-method="initialise" scope="singleton" />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:include name="myTransportMonitor" />
    <aop:include name="mySessionMonitor" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<bean id="myTransportMonitor" class="my.app.aspects.TransportMonitoringAspect"/>
<bean id="mySessionMonitor"   class="my.app.aspects.SessionMonitoringAspect" />
```

Aspect code

```
// Aspect monitoring code
@Aspect
public class SessionMonitoringAspect
{
    private Logger fileLogger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");

    public void initialise()
    {
        fileLogger.info("Initialising SessionMonitoringAspect");
    }

    @Pointcut ("execution (public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicOperation(){}

    @Pointcut ("within(my.app.session..*)")
    private void inSession(){}

    @Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && inSession()")
    private void sessionOperation(){}

    @Before("sessionOperation()")
    public void sessionOperationDetected(JoinPoint jp)
    {
        fileLogger.info("Session operation detected - signature: " + jp.getSignature());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer to put the Aspect pointcut configuration in the application context, and you are missing the ref in aop:aspect.

```
 <bean id="mySessionMonitor"   class="my.app.aspects.SessionMonitoringAspect" />

 <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:aspect ref="mySessionMonitor">
   <aop:pointcut id="around" expression="execution (public * *(..))"/></aop:pointcut>
   <aop:around pointcut-ref="around" method="aroundAdvice"/>
  </aop:aspect>
 </aop:config>
```

Comment: <aop:pointcut id="around" expression="execution (public * *(..))"/> @ Brain : </aop:pointcut>
   <aop:around pointcut-ref="around" method="aroundAdvice"/> ........ Can you please explain me these two lines.... Act I am also having a similar problem want to use your code in my case... but cant understand the above two lines...... thanks buddy...

Comment: The aop:pointcut property specifies the expression of where the advice should interceed. The id is the name you give it, which is then used in the aop:around line, and defines which method in your @Aspect it should run.

Answer (score 0):

I hope `initialise()` method is not part of `my.app.session.SessionImpl`. If so `initialise()` method of your Aspect will not fire. Because you cannot call aspect's method from bean class. Otherwise please attach `my.app.session.SessionImpl` code for detail understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer annotation-based configuration, see [this example](http://www.earldouglas.com/node/20) I wrote.  All you'll need in your XML configuration is `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`.